# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '16' in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have this json objects in posting action response:

```
{"status":"ok","filename":"538f057493d55.png"}
{"status":"ok","filename":"538f057493d11.png"}
```

i need to get filename value and add it to some hidden input, so i do this:

```
$.post(url, {image: src}).done(function(data){
    var status = data.status;
    if (status === "ok"){
        var filename = data.filename;
        $.each(filename, function(key, value){
            var photosInput = $('#images');
            photosInput.val(value);
        });
    } else {
       // error
    }
});
```

posting is work good but geting filename value displaying some error which is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '16' in 538f057493d55.png`. Thx for help.

Comment: You're iterating over the letters of your filename. What's the goal ?

Comment: what? can u be more specific?

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Where exactly is that exception triggered?

Comment: The JSON you now show isn't valid. Do you just receive a bunch of concatenated JSON strings ?

Comment: i have different response for different uploaded file, so i have file and one response for it, which is my json

Comment: Try setting dataType parameter to 'json' in $.post. Reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `$.each(filename,...` is iterating over the letters of your filename.

But you don't seem to need any iteration. It looks like jou just want

```
$.post(url, {image: src}).done(function(data){
    var status = data.status;
    if (status === "ok"){
        $('#images').val(data.filename);
    } else {
       // error
    }
});
```

If `data` is an array and you want to append all filenames to an input, you may do

```
$('#images').val(data.map(function(f){ return f.filename }).join(' '));
```

Comment: no i have more than one response from this posting and i have many jSON objects

Comment: @Lukas Please describe what you try to achieve. Because your code doesn't hint at the desired result.

Comment: @Lukas: Why did you only show one then? Your question sounds as if `data = {"status":"ok","filename":"538f057493d55.png"}`. If that is not the case, please edit it.

Comment: i can have more than one json object in posting resposne, like: `{"status":"ok","filename":"538f057493d55.png"}` and `{"status":"ok","filename":"538f057493d11.png"}`, now i need to iterate for this objects and get filename value to append them as a value for my images input

Comment: @Lukas: But in what data structure do you have them, is that an array? Please post the whole server response you're getting.

Comment: i have different response for difderent uploaded file, so i have file and one resposne for it, which is my json

Comment: You mean you do several $.post calls ?

Comment: No it's a one post call for actually sended photos.

Comment: So we only have a single object in `data`??? It might not be the same every time, but it's a single one every time? Or are you really sending invalid JSON, i.e. two consecutive object literals?

Comment: yeah, in data we have one object, for each file different and i need to catch them returned names